# Does Kalpa coincide with age of Sun?

Tags: time, surya, kalpa

While searching for relation between the life span of Sun and present Shri Bramha Day, I came across a very interesting fact by calculations. The age of our Sun is nearly equal to Shri Bramha's day i.e 14 Manavantar. We are half way in Shri Bramha's day i.e. 7th Manavantar. Please let me know if this is mentioned any where in Vedas.

If this is true it means that the Pralaya that will be coming at the end of this Kalpa is due to fire. The fire that will be emanating from the Sun due to its Red Giant nature towards the end of the Kalpa. Please let me know if this is true.

Comment: Apologies. There is a change in the calculation. Age of Sun approximately equal to a 28 Manavantars.

Comment: 1 Manavantar = 71 Mahayugas = 306,720,000 earth Years

By this equation, 

14 Manavantar = 4.294 billion earth years (Sun's Half life)

Thus Sun's remaining age is nearly equal to 1 Kalpa as per Vedic cosmological calculations